# Logical operators (and or operators) using R

Tags: r

Is there a way to simplify AND/OR logical operators?

Let's say I have the following rule:

> **a AND (b AND/OR c)**

Using the logical operators I will do as follow:

```
a & b & c | a & (b|c)
```

Can I do it so that I have something like `a & (b &| c)`?

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to `a AND (b OR c)` i.e `a & (b | c)` ?

Comment: What I am having doubts is the and/or thing.    a = 1 and (b = 1 or c = 1) means that b can be 0 and c = 1 OR  b = 1 and c = 0.

Comment: What is and/or supposed to mean? That's not an actual logical operator.

Comment: the rule is:  a == 1 AND (b== 1 AND/OR c ==1). How is this translated into R?

Comment: But what is AND/OR supposed to mean? It's not a valid logical operator. If it means (b AND c) OR (b OR c) then it's equivalent to b OR c.

Comment: Yes, it should mean (b AND c) OR (b OR c). Thanks Aplet123

Comment: So then it's just equivalent to b OR c, which would just be `b | c` in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down into two parts.

`a & b & c | a & (b|c)` can be `TRUE` if either `a & b & c` (Part 1) is `TRUE` OR `a & (b|c)` (Part2) is TRUE.

which means if all of `a`, `b` and `c` are `TRUE` (Part 1) OR

`a` is `TRUE` and either of `b` or `c` is TRUE.  (Part 2)

but if `a` and `b` is `TRUE` Part 2 is already `TRUE` so we don't really need `c` and part 1 then.

Hence, this ends up only with part 2 which is :

```
a & (b|c)
```